# Jquery - How to remove parent element if child element is without text?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I try to hide parent element li if child b is empty without success. Can you please tell me what I am doing wrong ? Thank you very much.

Jquery:

```
$('.mod-links li a b').each(function(){
       if($(this).text() == 0){
        $(this).parent('li').remove();
       }
});
```

HTML:

```
<ul class="mod-links ui-listview ui-listview-inset ui-corner-all ui-shadow" data-inset="true" data-theme="d" data-role="listview">
 <li class="ui-btn ui-btn-icon-right ui-li-has-arrow ui-li ui-btn-up-d" data-corners="false" data-shadow="false" data-iconshadow="true" data-wrapperels="div" data-icon="arrow-r" data-iconpos="right" data-theme="d"> <!-- parent element -->

    <div class="ui-btn-inner ui-li">
      <div class="ui-btn-text">
       <a class="small ui-link-inherit" href="/cz/cs/268_.html">
         <b></b> <!-- empty element -->
       </a>
      </div>
    <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrow-r ui-icon-shadow"> </span>
    </div> 

 </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **[:empty](http://api.jquery.com/empty/)** selector to select the empty `b` element as well as **[.closest()](http://api.jquery.com/empty/)** to get the closest ancestor `li` and remove it:

```
$('b:empty').closest('li').remove();
```

Answer (score 2):

Since there is no empty textnode in `b` you can use :empty selector

```
$('.mod-links li').has('a b:empty').remove()
```

If `b` can have blank spaces then

```
$('.mod-links li').filter(function () {
    return $.trim($(this).find('a b:empty').text()) == '';
}).remove()
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `if($(this).text() == 0){`, use `if($(this).is(":empty")){`.

jQuery:

```
$('.mod-links li a b').each(function(){
       if($(this).is(":empty")){
        $(this).closest('li').remove();
       }
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/L7FPJ/

Also note that I changed `.parent('li')` to `.closest('li')`, since `.parent` only retrieves elements from one level up the DOM tree.

Docs: [`.is`](http://api.jquery.com/is/), [`:empty`](http://api.jquery.com/empty-selector/), and [`.closest`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/).